# Checking if one list contains all elements of another element

Tags: java

I want to check if a List of characters like {a,a,d,e} is contained in a list like {a,d,e} in java. I want the answer to be false but I have no idea how to go about doing this. All help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Is the order important?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: *I have no idea how to go about doing this* - is not a valid question. If you can't solve the bigger problem, divide it to smaller ones.

Comment: no order isn't important.

Comment: Post your code that is working wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the retainAll() method and check for the result. col1.retainAll(col2) leaves all elements in col1 that are also in col2. If the size of col1 is the same before and after the call, the whole col2 is contained.